# Android chat, add new message showing

Tags: java, android

I'm working on chat activity with firebase and recyclerview. I've encountered little issue. When new message appears im using notifyItemInserted and then smoothScrollToPosition. When few first messages come (till screen is not full filled with messages) they are showing really smooth and it looks like same as in Facebook Messenger, but when it comes to scrolling to new message which is out of height our screen it pops up in blink of an eye which looks not good. I thought it has something to do with view recycling by recyclerview or with that smoothscrolling, but I dont know how to handle this.

Some asked code:

```
    mMessagesList.add(message);
    mChatRecyclerAdapter.notifyItemInserted(mChatRecyclerAdapter.getItemCount()-1);
    rvChatMessages.smoothScrollToPosition(mChatRecyclerAdapter.getItemCount()-1);
```

Could You guys share some tips with me?
Thanks

Comment: Try posting some of your code where you insert into the recyclerview so we get an idea of what you're working with - whenever I use notifyItemInserted, I have the smooth pop in you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

There is lots of unknown in your question but generally speaking if you are using RecyclerView (as you mentioned), you could improve your UI experience by using `reverseLayout` set to "true" in your `LinearLayoutManager` (my guess). Doing so would make your messages appear at the bottom of the list. This still has its own issues if you do paging, depending on how you do paging etc.

---

An update (key points from chat below) :

1. Use reverse LinearLayoutManager (option of constructor) - not the same as stackFromBottom
2. Add data to beginning of data collection (.add(0, ...)
3. Call notifyItemInserted(0) on adapter

Comment: Thanks for your answer im using in my LinearLayoutMenager method: setStackFromEnd(true), and it is working perfect but this is not issue at all. When for example: first 7 messages arrive (and they fit on screen and there is no need to use scrollToPosition) they are showing in recyclerview really really smooth. But when it comes to scroll to new messag which is appearing outside the view (outside screen) and then we scroll to it , this message is not showing that smooth.

Comment: Are your new messages appearing always at the bottom of the screen? I'm trying to understand why scrollToPosition is needed. I can imagine scroll is needed when, for example, user is several pages up the list, but not when the list is always appended at the bottom - there is always never message at the bottom.

Comment: If all done right (and if I got your point correctly), you should be doing `notifyItemInserted(0)` and not `notifyItemInserted(mChatRecyclerAdapter.getItemCount()-1)`

Comment: Oh, and there is difference between stackFromEnd and reverse layout. Please do check I believe it will be helpful!

Comment: I just tested out your updated answer so: without method smoothScrollToPosition new message shows below screen (i have to scroll to it by hand), but with method smoothScrollToPosition its the same issue as before :(

Comment: Do you have maybe some other tips?